# Vanilla JavaScript getAttribute("href") from link with image inside

Tags: javascript, html, image, href, getattribute

I am trying to create tabs with vanilla JavaScript, each tab has an icon and a title inside the link

```
<div class="tabs-bar-item">
  <a href="#tab3">
    <img class="icon" src="img/school.png">
    <h3 class="title">Instruktāžas datu aizsardzībā</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

It should open the tab content

```
<div id="tab3" class="tabs-content-item">
```

The problem is that `.getAttribute("href");` returns null when I have `<img>` and `<h3>` elements inside the link.
Everything works if I change the tab to

```
<div class="tabs-bar-item">
    <img class="icon" src="img/school.png">
    <a href="#tab3">Instruktāžas datu aizsardzībā</a>
</div>
```

but I want the tab content to open when clicked anywhere on `.tabs-bar-item`. How can it be done in vanilla JavaScript?

Full JS code:

```
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-bar .tabs-bar-item');

    function tabClicks(tabClickEvent) {
        for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            tabs[i].classList.remove("active");
        }

        let clickedTab = tabClickEvent.currentTarget; 

        clickedTab.classList.add("active");
        tabClickEvent.preventDefault();

        let contentPanes = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-content-item');

        for (i = 0; i < contentPanes.length; i++) {
            contentPanes[i].classList.remove("active");
        }

        let anchorReference = tabClickEvent.target;
        let activePaneId = anchorReference.getAttribute("href");
        let activePane = document.querySelector(activePaneId);

        activePane.classList.add("active");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].addEventListener("click", tabClicks)
    }
```

Css for tab content:

```
.tabs-content .tabs-content-item {
    display: none;
}
.tabs-content .tabs-content-item.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: If you're using #fragment URLs for tab navigation, you can do this in pure CSS with the :target pseudo-class. But just FYI, you code doesn't work because `tabClickEvent.currentTarget` will probably be a descendant of the link, not the link itself.

Comment: @Touffy I believe you mean `.target` rather than `.currentTarget`. The `.target` will always be the element actually clicked on - probably the img or h3 here. The `.currentTarget`, by definition, will be the element the handler is actually attached to, which here is the div surrounding the link. (Which of course doesn't have an href, but in fairness that's not what the OP is trying to get the href of.)

Comment: I guess your target element is wrong here. You can debug it with  `debugger` or try to use  `console.log(anchorReference);` to find out the issue.

Comment: Right, thanks Robin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) searchs up the DOM to find an element matching the selector passed as argument. If `Element` already matches the selector, `Element` (the node on which `closest` is called) is returned.

Hence try changing

```
 let anchorReference = tabClickEvent.target;
```

to

```
 let anchorReference = tabClickEvent.target.closest('a');
```

as for example in

```js
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-bar .tabs-bar-item');

function tabClicks(tabClickEvent) {
    for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].classList.remove("active");
    }

    let clickedTab = tabClickEvent.currentTarget;

    clickedTab.classList.add("active");
    tabClickEvent.preventDefault();

    let contentPanes = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-content-item');

    for (i = 0; i < contentPanes.length; i++) {
        contentPanes[i].classList.remove("active");
    }

    let anchorReference = tabClickEvent.target.closest('a');
    console.log( anchorReference);
    let activePaneId = anchorReference.getAttribute("href");
    let activePane = document.querySelector(activePaneId);

    activePane.classList.add("active");
}


for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].addEventListener("click", tabClicks)
}
```

```css
.tabs-content .tabs-content-item {
    display: none;
}
.tabs-content .tabs-content-item.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-bar">
  <div class="tabs-bar-item">
    <a href="#tab3">
      <img class="icon" src="img/school.png">
      <h3 class="title">Instruktāžas datu aizsardzībā</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=tabs-content>
  <div id="tab3" class="tabs-content-item">
     content of tab3 with self contained link: <a id="here" href="#here">here</a>. Clicking "here" should not close the tab!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! ```let anchorReference = tabClickEvent.target.closest('a');``` solved the problem

Comment: Calling preventDefault() on the click event breaks expected browser behaviour, like opening in a new tab or downloading the link when a modifier key is pressed. You can fix that by checking if the click even has one of those keys pressed.

Answer (score 1):

First off : you can do this in pure CSS with [the :target pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target), no JS needed.

```css
.tabs-content .tabs-content-item {
    display: none;
}
.tabs-content .tabs-content-item:target {
    display: block;
}
```

In the near future, you can also style the tab link for the currently open tab by using [the :local-link pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#local-link-pseudo).

In your code, `tabClickEvent.currentTarget` always refers to the DIV element that you attached the listener to. That element has no `href`. There are multiple ways to fix that. Removing the DIV altogether would be a good start, then you can attach a listener to the links, or make a global listener that checks if it's been clicked on a link or its descendant (using `element.closest('a')`).

Either way, properly implementing navigation with JavaScript is not as easy as you might think (this is also why the pure CSS solution is good). For example, if the user wants to open the link in a new (browser) tab, you'd have to add some code to read the page's fragment on load and open the correct tab without user interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am noticing however that  `:target` is being documented in a [Selectors Level 4 _draft_](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#target-pseudo) version without mention of dynamic use, which __is_  shown in [this example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target#a_table_of_contents). Unfortunately the example fails to mention an inbuilt shortcoming: if the target display is controlled by `:target` use in CSS, **and** the target has in internal link, taking the internal link kills display of the target. Not nice :)

Comment: Yeah, it has its limitations. It's been (ab)used for making interactive pure CSS pages for decades way more complex than tabs, so I wouldn't worry about the spec not saying explicitly that it reacts to navigation state dynamically. And it's not like :hover where you can have a feedback loop because of the reactivity. The URL can't be changed by CSS, only the other way around.

Comment: @traktor also, alongside :local-link, the near future has an answer to your limitation in the form of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target-within ;)